# Criterion for global dimension of subring

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, abstract-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

All rings are assumed to be associative and unital.

If $B$ is a commutative sub-ring of $A$ (which itself needs not be commutative) then what properties of $B$ are both necessary and sufficient for $D(B)\leq D(A)$ (where $D(-)$ denotes the global dimension)?

**For example**: the property: *$B$ is in the centre of $A$ and $B$ is a free as an $A$ module*
is sufficient for $D(A)\leq D(B)$
, but is there a tighter result?

Comment: You need to clear up the notation in the example.